# Regex to rename all files to different date format (python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a directory with files of the form 2018-1-7.csv and I need them to be 2018-01-07.csv

I have tried a few things but my regex-fu is weak. Can anyone suggest how to perform this?

Comment: I would use rename utility `rename 's/^(\d{4}-)(\d)-(\d)\b/\10\2-0\3/' *.csv`

Comment: `"%04i-%02i-%02i.csv" % tuple(int(i) for i in "2018-1-7.csv"[:-4].split('-'))`

Comment: What does the s part mean at the start @AvinashRaj ?

Comment: actually `s` is for [substitution operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html), more generally `s/(?<!\d)(?=\d(?!\d))/0/g` will add a 0 before every single digit

Comment: do you want to do this only through regex?? you can actually do it using datetime module in python with ease

Comment: Yes thank you, I ended up not using regex. I did something like what @Faibbus suggested, using .format notation instead of %